In sand vibrator why is the normal force greater than weight below equilibrium position?
In a sand vibrator, as we go downwards, the normal force increases upwards, and as we go upwards, the normal force decreases just to the point that the sand loses contact. I know the proof of this pattern is the direction of acceleration, but I don't understand how this happens. Do we take the force exerted by the vibrator in account anywhere? Shouldn't the contact force increase as the vibrator goes up since the vibrator is moving upwards?

idk. I am afraid to ask, but in the interest of education: what is a sand vibrator? Before you answer: this is a family site.
